# Avoid leaking out external types in a C++ class

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I have a class defined in a header like so (abbreviated):

```
class CairoRenderer
{
public:
    CairoRenderer();
    ~CairoRenderer();
...
protected:
    cairo_t* m_context;
    cairo_surface_t* m_surface;
};
```

cairo_t and cairo_surface_t are types defined by the [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) graphics library.

The problem I have is that if I want to use this class or its derived classes from another library or application, I need to include the cairo headers as well because I am "leaking" the cairo types out through the CairoRenderer header. I want this class (or any subclass of it) in the same library to be usable externally without needing to include the cairo header or link against the cairo libraries.

So the next thing I tried was to use the pimpl technique as per the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) example because it looked like it could do what I wanted to achieve:

CairoRenderer.h (abbreviated)

```
class CairoRenderer
{
...
protected:
    struct CairoRendererImpl;
    CairoRendererImpl* m_pimpl;
};
```

CairoRenderer.cpp (abbreviated)

```
#include "CairoRenderer.h"
#include "cairo.h"

....

struct CairoRenderer::CairoRendererImpl 
{
public:
    CairoRendererImpl() : m_surface(NULL), m_context(NULL) { }
    ~CairoRendererImpl() 
    {
        cairo_surface_destroy(m_surface);
        cairo_destroy(m_context);
    }

    void Initialize(cairo_t* context, cairo_surface_t* surface)
    {
        m_context = context;
        m_surface = surface;
    }

    cairo_surface_t* surface() { return m_surface; }
    cairo_t* context() { return m_context; }

private:
    cairo_surface_t* m_surface;
    cairo_t* m_context;
};

CairoRenderer::CairoRenderer() : m_pimpl(new CairoRendererImpl()) { ... }

CairoRenderer::~CairoRenderer() { delete m_pimpl; }
```

The problem I have is when I try to access the m_pimpl member from a derived class, I get the compiler error:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'CairoRenderer::CairoRendererImpl'
```

Am I doing pimpl wrong? Or is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Why do you want to access the pimpl from a derived class? The whole raison d'etre of the pimpl is to hide implementation details of a class. If at all then derived classes should only use the base class' interface.

Comment: Main objective is to hide cairo_t and cairo_surface_t from external code. Pimpl looked like the solution, but obviously wasn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the pimpl idiom correctly, and that is your problem. You have hidden the definition of `CairoRendererImpl` from **all** external code, *including* the code in derived classes.

First of all I would like to call into question the value of having a base class that has data members and a non-virtual destructor. You should look at the underlying reasons that you want to subclass `CairoRenderer`, and consider alternative solutions.

If you *do* want to support subclassing, but only for the classes within your library, then you should put the definition of `CairoRendererImpl` into a shared header file that can be included by the implementation files of all of the relevant classes in the `CairoRenderer` heirachy.

Comment: so protected doesn't do what I thought it does in this context?

Comment: Your suggested solution, which was further explained in detail by @haavee did the trick! Cheers.

Comment: @jumpinjackie I can't answer that without knowing what you think protected does,but-The important thing to notice is that access specifications apply to names, not to things. `protected` allows subclasses to use the name `CairoRenderer::CairoRendererImpl` (for example, to declare arguments to functions, or data members), but even if `CairoRenderer::CairoRendererImpl` was `private`, subclasses could still use and access `m_pimpl` if `m_pimpl` was declared `protected`. The reason that your code was not compiling was that you were attempting to use a class that had been declared, but not defined.

Comment: The reason was _not_ that you were attempting to access a protected member (or a protected nested type).

Answer (score 1):

The pimpl idiom used ok.

The way to avoid having to include the cairo.h file(s) is to have, in your CairoRenderer.h file the statement (ie a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration))

```
class CairoRendererImpl;
```

and leave it at that; do *not* include CairoRendererImpl.h since that will NEED to drag in definitions of cairo.h.

You can do this because CairoRenderer only needs a *pointer* to an implementation - as long as you do not actually call any methods from the headerfile (e.g. inline functions) the compiler doesn't need to see the full declaration of the CairoRendererImpl class.

In the CairoRenderer.cc you can include the CairoRendererImpl.h file (which will get the cairo.h stuff but at this point that is what you actually want/need).

hth,
h

Answer (score 0):

I think `struct CairoRenderer::CairoRendererImpl` is wrong. Since you do not use namespaces, a simple definition like this would suffice:

```
struct CairoRendererImpl 
{
    ...
}
```

Also you have to adjust your `CairoRenderer` class a bit:

```
struct CairoRendererImpl;

class CairoRenderer
{
...
protected:
    CairoRendererImpl* m_pimpl;
};
```

Comment: This is not the problem. `CairoRenderer::CairoRendererImpl` is the correct way to refer to `CairoRendererImpl`.